# Admob using Storyboard - UIView may not respond to viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c

I've been searching and changing code for 2 days.  I'm using xcode 4.5 and storyboards.  I got admob to work on my main view, but I've added 50+ other views, and getting a couple warnings and the ads will not show up.

```
//  ViewMain2.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GADBannerView.h"

@class GADBannerView, GADRequest;
@interface ViewMain2 : UIView 
<GADBannerViewDelegate> {
    GADBannerView *adBanner_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) GADBannerView *adBanner;

- (GADRequest *)createRequest;
- (UIView *)view;

@end

//////////  ViewMain2.m

#import "ViewMain2.h"
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADRequest.h"

@implementation ViewMain2

@synthesize adBanner = adBanner_;

- (UIView *)view {
    return (UIView *)self.view;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark init/dealloc

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view,
// typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Initialize the banner at the bottom of the screen.
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                                 self.view.frame.size.height -
                                 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);

    // Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
    self.adBanner = [[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner
                                                    origin:origin]
                     autorelease];

    // Note: Edit SampleConstants.h to provide a definition for kSampleAdUnitID
    // before compiling.
    self.adBanner.adUnitID = @"a1512d23a796691";
    self.adBanner.delegate = self;
    [self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
    self.adBanner.center =
    CGPointMake(self.window.center.x, self.adBanner.center.y);
    [self.adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    adBanner_.delegate = nil;
    [adBanner_ release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

#pragma mark GADRequest generation

// Here we're creating a simple GADRequest and whitelisting the application
// for test ads. You should request test ads during development to avoid
// generating invalid impressions and clicks.
- (GADRequest *)createRequest {
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    // Make the request for a test ad. Put in an identifier for the simulator as
    // well as any devices you want to receive test ads.
    request.testDevices =
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
     // TODO: Add your device/simulator test identifiers here. They are
     // printed to the console when the app is launched.
     nil];
    return request;
}

#pragma mark GADBannerViewDelegate impl

// We've received an ad successfully.
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView {
    NSLog(@"Received ad successfully");
}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}

@end
```

I'm getting a warning "UIView may not respond to viewDidLoad" on the line -> [super viewDidLoad];

I'm also getting a warning "Incompatible pointer types sending ViewMain2 to parameter of type UIViewController" on the line -> [self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];

I've tried a lot of tutorials and searching, but with all the views in storyboard named UIView, I'm struggling.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You declare your class to be a subclass of `UIView`:

```
@interface ViewMain2 : UIView
```

However, you are trying to use it as a `UIViewController`. Decide which one you want - if a view controller, then change the superclass to `UIViewController`, if a view, then don't try to use it as a view controller.